# How to install system drivers after a clean install of W10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, installation, clean-install

Ive got an error on a windows 10 HP laptop with the OS and i need to do a clean install of the W10.

Ive never done a windows clean install (done plenty of Mac ones) so im trying to figure out everything i need in advance.

So far my plan is to :

- backup all data
- download W10 from microsoft [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) , install it onto a USB drive, boot into the drive and run the installer

Once the clean install of W10 is complete as i understand i need to install drivers for various bits of hardware, for this HP have a driver page for my laptop [HERE](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-15-ay100-notebook-pc/12499456/model/13556511). Where i currently cant make my mind up is wether i should download the individual drivers from that page and install them (the issue with this is im a bit confused on some of them as there seem to be 2 bluetooth drivers, and other options on a couple of other drivers, due to what hardware the specific laptop has).

I was also told to check out the HP Setup Assistant software which apperently functions like a driver install wizard, by scanning your hardware and then downloading the required drivers.

What is preferable to download the individual drivers or the use the HP setup assistant ?

Is there also a test / tool i can run at the end of the processes after the new OS and drivers have been installed, to check nothing is missing ?

Will i need to enable security features etc, or does a clean copy of W10 default to a locked down mode ?

Comment: Do not use hp software to download device drivers, it's not required, everything you need can individually downloaded from the HP website or Windows Update

Comment: "Is there also a test / tool i can run at the end of the processes after the new OS and drivers have been installed, to check nothing is missing?" -Device Manager

Comment: My experience has been that Windows also installs needed drivers, in most cases (MS rather than OEM), and that afterwards only a few need to be manually updated. Allow the installation process to have internet access to find drivers. That said, I would image the whole disk, should an essential driver (e.g. video or keyboard), fails.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read through my answer in the question that I referenced.  Utilizing that method, you can easily ensure that all of your device drivers restored.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Answer (score 0):

Drivers may be automatically installed or they may not. It is easier to use the HP setup assistant to scan and automatically find your drivers. Only thing is that sometimes you may not be able to use it if you do not have a ethernet adapter driver, which means you won't have internet. So it is best to download the ethernet adapter manually first just in case. Then after a clean install check what drivers you need by going to "Device Manager". As long as you have the Ethernet Adapter installed you can go the HP website and use the HP Setup assistant.

Comment: In my experience dealing HO software that scans then installs drivers either incompatible drivers are installed (if you are lucky) or the program just crashes

Comment: Yeah, it may not be 100% reliable but in my experience it works most of the time installing maybe all drivers except one. For Sam, I think it would be easier than digging through all the drivers. You may have one missing after the scan and install but check in Device Manager and search for that last driver manually.